# Enabling `exponent-to-prefix` functionality for unitless values

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

With `siunitx` package, `exponent-to-prefix` option seems to work only if there is a unit with the given number (`\SI`, `\SIrange`, and `\SIlist`). I want the option to work even with unitless values (given by `\num`, `\numrange`, `\numlist`). In the picture below, all the numeric exponents following a unitless number should be replaced with their standard symbols

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation=engineering,exponent-to-prefix=false,zero-decimal-to-integer=true}

\begin{document}

\num{10e6}

\numrange{3e3}{70e5}

\numlist{3e3; 70e5; 150e9}

\SI{10e6}{\meter}

\SIrange{3e3}{70e5}{\meter}

\SIlist{3e3; 70e5; 150e9}{\meter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the closest to what you want is to use a 'do nothing' unit

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = engineering, exponent-to-prefix = true, zero-decimal-to-integer = true}
\DeclareSIUnit{\noop}{\kern 0pt}
\begin{document}

\SI{10e6}{\noop}

\SIrange{3e3}{70e5}{\noop}

\SIlist{3e3; 70e5; 150e9}{\noop}

\end{document}
```

(Prefixes are fundamentally associated with units.)

Comment: Sometimes mentioning units can be redundant but it is still better replace exponents with suffixes following a number. Is it possible to include this in the next version of `siunitx` as an option to work with unitless values given by `\num`, `\numrange`, and `\numlist`?